# Vuetify combobox - How to disable typing in vuetify's combobox

Tags: vue.js, combobox, vuetify.js

The vuetify combobox is allowing the user to type inside the combobox. Any clue on how to disable this.

This is how I have implemented my combobox.

```
<v-combobox
:loading="isSurveyBeingPopulated"
class="static--inputs"
color="red"
box
:items="folders"
:rules="[rules.required]"
item-text="value"
dense
placeholder="Select Survey Folder"
item-value="key"
slot="input"
v-model="selectedSurveyFolder">
</v-combobox>
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Combobox:

> The v-combobox component is a v-autocomplete that allows the user to
>   enter values that do not exist within the provided items. Created
>   items will be returned as strings.

So if you want to disable the typing you should use a select:  https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/selects

> Select fields components are used for collecting user provided
>   information from a list of options.

Comment: But what if you still want to have the ability to filter but not the ability to add new text?

Comment: Select has a filter property you could use or else you could use https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/autocompletes

Comment: Very late to the party, but I was looking for this answer because I thought the <v-select> component didn't have an "item" slot. Turns out it does, I just needed to stop looking at the Component Page (https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/selects/#slots) and start looking at the API page (https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-select/#slots). The component page doesn't list all the Slots.

Answer (score 2):

You can just delete new item after changed.

```
<v-combobox
    v-model="selected"
    :items="[...selected, ...items]"
    multiple
    @change="onChangeCombobox"
/>
```

```
onChangeCombobox(items) {
  this.selected = items.filter((item) => this.items.includes(item))
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I've gone thru the same, i need combobox to list item and custom values but i must disable typing, my solutions was to use key events and "change"its behavior like:

```
    @keydown="$event.target.blur()"
    @keypress="$event.target.blur()"
    @keyup="$event.target.blur()"
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, I used v-select instead of v-combobox, it works fine:

```
<v-select
  return-object
></v-select>
```

Comment: the problem is I want to render Item with extra things so I want Combobox but do not want typing

Answer (score -2):

Yes, you can achieve filtering of a combobox by using the rules code, e.g.

```
  <v-combobox
    v-model="selection"
    :items="items"
    :search-input.sync="input"
    :rules="intRule"
    chips
    clearable
    dense
    multiple
    small-chips
    item-text="title"
    autocomplete="off"
    return-object
  >
  </v-combobox>
```

and then in your script section in data, sth like

```
data() {
    return {
      selection: [],
      input: null,
      items: [],
      valid: false,
      intRule: [
        function(v) {
          if (!v || v.length < 0) {
            return false
          } else if (v.length > 0) {
            for (let i = 0; i < v.length; i++) {
              if (/[^0-9]/g.test(v[i].id)) {
                v.splice(-1, 1)
                return false
              }
            }
            return false
          } else {
            return true
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

the `input` could be used to overwrite a no results slot and show for what input are no results found.

hope this is helping

Comment: The question is about something completely different - how to disable typing.

Comment: > But what if you still want to have the ability to filter but not the ability to add new text? 
... this is the answer to this

Comment: @silvan literally the library tells you to use v-select instead of v-combobox if you don't want the user to type in there lol

Comment: ... filter by typing is not possible in v-select.

https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/selects/#selection

but yes, nowadays you probably better go here: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/autocompletes/#props